# Why do I get corrupt output on my file?

Tags: c++, int, fstream, short

I have a simple program which I have compiled in both MinGW and Visual C++ 2008 Express, and both give an output file larger than 88200.  When I set s = 0, both programs work as expected.  What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    short s;

    fstream f;

    f.open("test.raw", ios_base::out);

    for(i = 0; i < 44100; i++)
    {
        s = i & 0xFFFF; // PROBLEM?
        f.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&s), sizeof(s));
    }

    f.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that this sort of thing will not port across architectures of different endian-ness. (At least, you will not be able to read the file written by one back on the other.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
f.open("test.raw", ios_base::out | ios_base::binary);
```

When you write out `char`s that happen to match the newline character `\n` they are being converted to the standard windows newline sequence `\r\n`. Opening the file in binary mode stops this conversion from being performed.